# Aggregate highlights from PDF?

Tags: ios, pdf

Is there an app that I can use to highlight blocks of text in a PDF and then export the highlights - pretty much the same thing as iBooks does with EPUB?

Answer (score 1):

I would use this for that purpose http://highlightsapp.net/